# How to restart a BASH script from itself with a signal?

Tags: bash, unix, signals

For example I have script with an infinite loop printing something to stdout. I need to trap a signal (for example SIGHUP) so it will restart the script with different PID and the loop will start itself again from 0.  Killing and starting doesn't work as expected:

```
function traphup(){  
    kill $0  
    exec $0
}  
trap traphup HUP
```

Maybe I should place something in background or use nohup, but I am not familiar with this command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function:

```
traphup(){
    $0 "$@" &
    exit 0
}
```

This starts a new process in the background with the original command name and arguments (vary arguments to suit your requirements) with a new process ID.  The original shell then exits.  Don't forget to sort out the PID file if your daemon uses one to identify itself - but the restart may do that anyway.

Note that using `nohup` would be the wrong direction; the first time you launched the daemon, it would respond to the HUP signal, but the one launched with `nohup` would ignore the signal, not restarting again - unless you explicitly overrode the 'ignore' status, which is a bad idea for various reasons.

---

#### Answering comment

I'm not quite sure what the trouble is.

When I run the following script, I only see one copy of the script in `ps` output, regardless of whether I start it as `./xx.sh` or as `./xx.sh &`.

```
#!/bin/bash

traphup()
{
    $0 "$$" &
    exit 0
}

trap traphup HUP
echo
sleep 1

i=1
while [ $i -lt 1000 ]
do
    echo "${1:-<none>}: $$: $i"
    sleep 1
    : $(( i++ ))
done
```

The output contains lines such as:

```
<none>: 1155: 21
<none>: 1155: 22
<none>: 1155: 23

1155: 1649: 1
1155: 1649: 2
1155: 1649: 3
1155: 1649: 4
```

The ones with '`<none>`' are the original process; the second set are the child process (1649) reporting its parent (1155).  This output made it easy to track which process to send HUP signals to.  (The initial echo and sleep gets the command line prompt out of the way of the output.)

My suspicion is that what you are seeing depends on the content of your script - in my case, the body of the loop is simple.  But if I had a pipeline or something in there, then I might see a second process with the same name.  But I don't think that would change depending on whether the original script is run in foreground or background.

Comment: Thanks. Only one thing is not really clear to me. If i run my script in traphup() in foreground and then grep ps result with name of my script - i will get two items with different PID. But if i run scipt in background - i will get only one record with new pid. Thats what i needed, but why there is difference in these types of executing?

Comment: You don't need the colon: `(( i++ ))` works by itself (but I would have used a `for` loop there). *[I don't mean to be critical - my intent is to be constructive.]*

Comment: I normally use a program `for i in $(range 1 1000)` which works nicely for me, but doesn't help people who don't have it.  I'm out of practice at doing stuff like that in Bash - I have to work on machines where it is not the standard shell, and too much adapting to Bash is ultimately counter-productive to me.

Comment: Sorry for lame question, but why i should execute script in traphup() in background? What's wrong with a regular exec `$0`?

Comment: @Oink: If you use exec, you will keep the same PID. You wanted a different PID.

Comment: @camh: I mean changing `$0 "$$" &` to `$0 "$$"`

Comment: @Oink: the quotes around $$ are unnecessary.  At one time, I was going to use "$@" (which does need the quotes), but $$ was both simpler and sufficient (and made the quotes unnecessary).

Comment: Most likely it was hard to explain what was not clear for me. We have to run script after restart signal in background because otherwise it will never get `exit 0` so that's why i had both scripts (current and started after signal) running in ps output. Now it's clear.